# PHP - merge two different data source in single source

Tags: php, html

I may mistitled this question here but i will explain what I want for you guys>>

so basically I have two data sources:

1. url that outputs pdf pages
2. another php file that outputs html

so what i simply want is to get the content of these sources from single file which would be the php file.

what i have in mind is to use file_get_contents function to inject my php file with those pdf pages but im not sure if this is right or good idea

any ideas how to do that ??? im really stuck guys

Comment: If you just want a page that displays both, use file_get_contents for both, then just output that on the same page

Comment: aha like making a third page and use file_get_contents for both urls?
@clearshot66

Comment: Yes that's one way

Comment: any other solutions? i know this is the easiest way to do this
@clearshot66

Comment: We'd need to see your code

Comment: @clearshot66 when i used file_get_contents to show content of url that has pdf it doesn't work

Comment: Show-your-code lol